# Problems installing QGIS on Windows Vista

Tags: qgis, installation

I have tried several times on several windows vista machines to install QGIS (both versions 2.10.1 and 2.8) but with no luck. 
It seems to install fine without any errors but when the installation is finished QGIS is nowhere to be found. There is no short cut created on the desktop and it does not appear when I search in the start menu.

I have very basic computer knowledge and have simply followed the onscreen instructions and not altered anything else.

It works perfectly on my windows 7 and 8 machines.

Comment: I think it might be hard for someone to help you based on that information. Vista has been out of support for some time, so would it not be better to upgrade you windows versions, seeing as you say it works on newer ones?

Comment: Do you install with OSGeo4W? It may be enough to find and run the qgis.bat file from OSGeo4W\bin directory. Or perhaps from the OSGeo4W command window.

Comment: I wish we had the budget to upgrade all of the laptops definitely would have been the preferred option. Only just got rid of xp!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to install QGIS, and you don't mention where you are getting it. Assuming you are using the QGIS standalone installer, I *highly* recommend that you switch to the  [OSGeo4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) installer. I have run it successfully on WinXP, Vista, and 7.

Just do the Express Desktop Install, and if you don't want the other GIS software included by default (uDig and a handful of others), uncheck everything except QGIS.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was using the stand alone. This has solved everything!

Answer (score 1):

If no shortcuts are created, the installation was **not** finished successfully.

You can look out for the file `postinstall.log` within the programmes tree, and compare it with that of a successful installation.

BTW QGIS still runs on 32bit Windows XP, so the OS should not be the reason.